# Sql update with where not in

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have this information in table ps_product_lang:

```
id_product  id_lang
1           1  
1           2
1           3
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           1
5           2
5           3
```

the output should be

```
id_product  id_lang
1           1  
1           2
1           3
2           2
3           2
4           2
5           1
5           2
5           3
```

I would like to update the record which has an unique id_product and the id_lang should be 1 that's mean that concern the 4th , 5th and 6th record:

I tried this query but it doesn't work

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` p 
SET    p.`id_lang` = '2' 
WHERE  p.`id_lang` = '1' 
       AND p.id_product NOT IN (SELECT `id_product` 
                                FROM   `ps_product_lang` ps 
                                WHERE  p.id_product = ps.id_product 
                                       AND ps.id_lang = '2');
```

Comment: not getting clear idea what you exactly want to do....

Comment: Not clear what you want.read your question i think you are missing or provide wrong information.

Comment: i would like to update the record which has id_lang 1 and which has an unique id_product in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this as you make , but just make an inner select .

```
 UPDATE `ps_product_lang`  
 SET    `id_lang` = '2' 
 WHERE  `id_lang` = '1' 
   AND id_product NOT IN (select `id_product` from (SELECT `id_product` 
                            FROM   `ps_product_lang`  
                            WHERE  id_product = id_product 
                                   AND id_lang = '2')t );
```

[**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c47314/1)

Comment: MySQL has a really bad performance problem with UPDATE WHERE IN (). You should always use UPDATE INNER JOIN!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id_product
  FROM ps_product_lang
  GROUP BY id_product
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  ) b ON b.id_product = p.id_product
SET p.`id_lang` = '2'
WHERE p.`id_lang` = '1'
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6feea/1)</kbd>

The inner query gets you only the rows with unique product_id and you UPDATE the ones that have id_lang = 1.

Answer (score 0):

you have a contradiction in your request:

```
p.id_product not in
```

against

```
p.id_product= ps.id_product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` p 
SET    p.`id_lang` = '2' 
WHERE  p.`id_lang` = '1' 
AND id_product IN(SELECT id_product FROM
(SELECT  id_product FROM ps_product_lang GROUP BY    id_product HAVING COUNT(*)=1 )as x)
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dd9d/1)